# li tag loop issue jquery php

Tags: php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I'm trying to get the the text of `<li>` using `jquery`  and `php`  although my `jquery ajax` call is retrieving and displaying my `<li>`  when i use the onclick to display the text  it is only alerting the first value  for each `<li>` displayed on the page

```
    <?php
      foreach ($query->result() as $row){
               // produce li tag 
              echo '<li id="select_cat" onclick="select_category()">'.$row->category_name.'</li>';        

                }


     ?>
```

jquery

```
       $(document).ready(function(){
               $.ajax({
                   type:"GET",
                   url: "<?=base_url()?>" + "categories/display_categories_for_modal", 
                   success: function(res){
                     $("#main_categories").html(res); 
                     }
                });
               });
   function select_category(){
           var category = $("select_cat").text();
             alert(category);
   // every <li> clicked on always alerts the text of the first <li> e.g electronics
```

}

html

```
    <ul id="main_categories">



     </ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your foreach loop, you need to pass the id of the li element via the **this** keyword.

**Change from:**

```
echo '<li id="select_cat" onclick="select_category()">'.$row->category_name.'</li>';
```

**To:**

```
echo '<li id="select_cat" onclick="select_category(this)">'.$row->category_name.'</li>';
```

In your js script, add li parameter to your select_category() function.

**Change from:**

```
function select_category(){
           var category = $("select_cat").text();
             alert(category);
   // every <li> clicked on always alerts the text of the first <li> e.g electronics 
}
```

**Change To:**

```
select_category = function (li){
                var category = $(li).text();
                alert(category);
            }
```

^ And put the function inside `$(document).ready(function(){ ... });` to prevent error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` - Appears if a jquery function is called when jquery or document is not ready yet.

**New PHP Code:**

```
   <?php
      foreach ($query->result() as $row){
               // produce li tag 
              echo '<li id="select_cat" onclick="select_category(this);">'.$row->category_name.'</li>';        

       }
     ?>
```

**New JS Code:**

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
             type:"GET",
               url: "" + "categories/display_categories_for_modal", 
               success: function(res){
                 $("#main_categories").html(res); 
                 }
        });

        select_category = function (li){
            var category = $(li).text();
            alert(category);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Yes your solution worked  i appreciate that thank you

Comment: @chriskeenan if this is the working solution you need to accept it so it gets the big green tick.

Answer (score 0):

The element that triggered the event is bound to the function as `this`, so you should be able to fetch the category by simply doing this:

```
var category = $(this).text();
```

Comment: i tried this the alert is blank        
console is display Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined